# Удаление строки после /

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Например есть строка [http://сайт.ру/уровень1/уровень2.html](http://%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82.%D1%80%D1%83/%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C1/%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C2.html)
Мне нужно получить [http://сайт.ру](http://%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82.%D1%80%D1%83)
Никак не могу разобраться в регулярками( Помогите пожалуйста

Comment: вот гляньте https://regex101.com/r/AzAorA/1/ (и уточните вопрос - могут ли содержаться цифры в именах, английские буквы, обязательно ли начинаются со схемы)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно обойтись без явного использования регулярок и воспользоваться классом `java.net.URL`:

```
URL url = new URL("http://сайт.ру/уровень1/уровень2.html");
String site = String.format("%s://%s", url.getProtocol(), url.getAuthority());
System.out.println(site); // http://сайт.ру
```

Comment: s/Можно/Нужно/;

Answer (score 0):

Можете попробовать так:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String url = "http://сайт.ру/уровень1/уровень2.html";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(http|https)://([а-я\\w\\-\\.]+)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(url);
    if(m.find())
        System.out.println(m.group());// вывод: http://сайт.ру
}
```

`"^(http|https)://([а-я\\w\\-\\.]+)"` означает, что адрес начинается с `http` или `https`, после этого `://` и все что попадает до первого `/` (русские маленькие буквы, английские буквы, цифры, точка, тире).